# how to clear insufficient space on disk where the following directory resides in teamcity

Tags: teamcity, diskspace

I am getting the following message :-

```
Warning: insufficient space on disk where the following directory resides: Z:\TeamCity\.BuildServer\system. Disk space available: 915.53Mb. Please contact your system administrator.
```

I already have executed the build history cleanup command. but this has not done much. Can you please guide what directory under the following path I clear up to make space on disk.

This Z:\TeamCity.BuildServer\system path has artifacts, caches, changes, messages directories. Which directory to delete to make space. 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look to the Clean-up process settings: <s>http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/ITProfessionals/ITProcesses/don-t-forget-to-clean</s>

[Wayback Machine Archive Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150318192124/http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/itprofessionals/itprocesses/don-t-forget-to-clean/)

By default TeamCity kepts everything forever, you must configure clean-up rules for each project.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).